# R ggplot2: custom y-axis tick labels for log-transformed data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

Most tutorials I've seen for dealing with transforming log-based data involve using a log-based y-axis or x-axis scale. If I wanted to plot the log<sub>10</sub>  -based values of my data and indicate their relative actual exponent-based real values:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

a <- c(5,10,15,20)
b <- c(100,210,350,750)
d <- log10(b)

test_df <- data.frame(xval = a,yval = d)
test_plt <- ggplot(data = test_df,aes(x = xval,y = yval)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,3,by = 1),limits = c(1,3),labels = trans_format("log10", 
math_format(10^.x)))

print(test_plt)
```

Based on the code, I get the following results:

[image: Log10-based plot]

Obviously, R is trying to convert the already log<sub>10</sub>-transformed values into log<sub>10</sub> based values again, is there a way indicate that I want my y-axis tick values to be 10<sup>1</sup>, 10<sup>2</sup>, 10<sup>3</sup>, etc. (ie: the the plotted values are log<sub>10</sub> transformed, but the y-ticks indicate the actual values before the log<sub>10</sub> transformation? Or am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

Comment: Are you looking for `scales::math_format(format = log10)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `math_format()` with its default arguments:

```
test_plt <- ggplot(data = test_df,aes(x = xval,y = yval)) +
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,3,by = 1),
                       limits = c(1,3),
                       labels = math_format())

print(test_plt)
```

[image]

From `help("math_format")`:

```
Usage
... [Some content omitted]...

math_format(expr = 10^.x, format = force)
```

This is *exactly* the formatting you want, `10^.x`, rather than `10^.x` **after** a `log10` transformation, which is what you get when you call it *within* `trans_format("log10", 
math_format(10^.x))`

Comment: This is just what I needed! Thanks for the help!